# How to close menu list by click in to component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem with closing menu item in vue and vuetify2.
I got something like this:

```
<v-menu
            transition="slide-y-transition"
            bottom
            left
            offset-y
            nudge-bottom="2"
            :close-on-click="!activeTour"
          >
            <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                icon
                class="ml-md-4"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
              >
                <v-icon>
                  mdi-plus-circle
                </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
            <v-list-item>
              <WorkRegistryDialog class="work-registry-activator">
                <template #activator="{ on: dialog, attrs }">
                  <v-list-item-title
                    v-bind="attrs"
                    v-on="dialog"
                    @click="zamknij"
                  >
                  {{ $t("add_entry") }}
                  </v-list-item-title>
                </template>
              </WorkRegistryDialog>
            </v-list-item>
```

And i want close menu when i click on v-list-item which contains WorkRegistryDialog but it is not working. Can someone please help me?

I have tried to add js listeners but with failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<template>
         <v-menu
+           v-model="showMenu"
            transition="slide-y-transition"
            bottom
            left
            offset-y
            nudge-bottom="2"
            :close-on-click="!activeTour"
          >
            <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                icon
                class="ml-md-4"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
              >
                <v-icon>
                  mdi-plus-circle
                </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
-           <v-list-item>
+           <v-list-item @click="showMenu = false">
              <WorkRegistryDialog class="work-registry-activator">
                <template #activator="{ on: dialog, attrs }">
                  <v-list-item-title
                    v-bind="attrs"
                    v-on="dialog"
                    @click="zamknij"
                  >
                  {{ $t("add_entry") }}
                  </v-list-item-title>
                </template>
              </WorkRegistryDialog>
            </v-list-item>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank for Your help but this solution is not working :( Any idea?

Comment: my answer is taken from vuetify's document if it doesn't work make sure the code you provide is complete or you need to provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Yeah, You provide correct answer. :) But the problem is in WorkRegistryDialog module. I have to open this as dialog and then close menu. I don't know how to do this. :(